# Datagridview cellFormat is not working to Format from old string to new string - C#

Tags: json, c#-4.0, datagridview, cell-formatting

I'm fetching my Data from a json source. then I will Cast it to a class type then i set it to datagridview's Datasource.

The value for this column is something like:

**12A12345**

I want to be able to format it this like:

**12-A-123-45WR**

```
private void dgvListDrivers_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            int value;
            if (e.Value != null)
            {
                e.CellStyle.Format = "##-#-###-##WR"; 
                e.FormattingApplied = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

but this code not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i could solve the problem:

```
 if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            //int value;
            if (e.Value != null)
            {
                string value = e.Value.ToString();
                if(value.Length==8)
                    e.Value = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}WR", value.Substring(0, 2), value.Substring(2, 1), value.Substring(3, 3), value.Substring(6, 2));
                e.FormattingApplied = true;
            }
        }
```